# JDK 8 update 66 fatal error for JavaFx application on Windows 10

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx, jvm, javafx-8

I'm making a JavaFx app. Today I integrated a login panel and a registration panel to it. After integrating those, I started getting a fatal error whenever I ran the app which didn't happen earlier. The log of the error is as follows:

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> EXCEPTION_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION (0xc000001d) at pc=0x000007feec5d5c01, pid=5552, tid=4252
>
> JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_66-b17) (build 1.8.0_66-b17)
>   Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.66-b17 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
>   Problematic frame:
>   C  [msvcr120.dll+0x95c01]
>
> Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

OS: *Windows 10* (64 bit)
Java: *JDK 8u66*
IDE: *Netbeans 8.0.1*

---

I also ran the app on a system with *Ubuntu 14.04* 64 bit (*JDK 8u77* and *Netbeans 8.0.2*) and the **app ran fine** without any fatal errors (or any errors).

The thing that I want to know is that, is it a development issue or a JVM issue? Should I just raise an issue and continue with JDK 8u77?

Comment: This does point to a bug in the windows version of Java, or in the windows DLL it is using.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue in Java, which is being looked into - https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8157447