# JavaFX - SVGPath and PathTransition(Animate a node along a svgpath)

Tags: java, animation, svg, javafx

I am having a hard time trying to animate a node along a svgPath, I followed [this](http://www.hameister.org/JavaFX_SVGPath.html) tutorial but when I run the code I get the following error:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

  EXCEPTION_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION (0xc000001d) at pc=0x000007fef80d5c01, pid=5984, tid=5828

 JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_65-b17) (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.65-b01 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [msvcr120.dll+0x95c01]
```

So... any idea of how to get around this error?? Or is there a better way to animate a node along a svgPath (`PathTransition`).

Comment: Same problem over there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36679299/jdk-8-update-66-fatal-error-for-javafx-application-on-windows-10

Comment: This could be a graphic driver issue. Have you tried this using a x86 JRE (32-Bit)? I had on one of my machines a lot of trouble with this issue in the x64 JRE-Version, but in the x86 not. So maybe you'll give it a try.

Comment: Ok... I'll try it... It makes sense.